# VirtualQueryEx() returns mostly useless data

Tags: winapi

I've written a little program to query the page-map of a process:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <charconv>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    if( argc < 2 )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    try
    {
        DWORD dwProcessId = [&]() -> DWORD
            {
                DWORD dwRet;
                from_chars_result fcr = from_chars( argv[1], argv[1] + strlen( argv[1] ), dwRet );
                if( fcr.ec != errc() || *fcr.ptr )
                    throw invalid_argument( "process-id unparseable" );
                return dwRet;
            }();
        HANDLE hProcess = [&]() -> HANDLE
            {
                HANDLE hRet = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwProcessId );
                if( !hRet )
                    throw system_error( (int)GetLastError(), system_category(), "can't open process" );
                return hRet;
            }();
        size_t pageSize = []() -> size_t
            {
                SYSTEM_INFO si;
                GetSystemInfo( &si );
                return si.dwPageSize;
            }();
        using mbi_t = MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION;
        vector<mbi_t> mbis( 0x100 );
        size_t nRegions;
        while( !(nRegions = VirtualQueryEx( hProcess, nullptr, to_address( mbis.begin() ), mbis.size() * sizeof(mbi_t) )) )
            if( GetLastError() == ERROR_BAD_LENGTH )
                mbis.resize( mbis.size() * 2 );
            else
                throw system_error( (int)GetLastError(), system_category(), "can't query process pages" );
        mbis.resize( nRegions );
        for( mbi_t const &mbi : mbis )
        {
            cout << "base address: " << hex << mbi.BaseAddress << endl;
            cout << "allocation base: " << hex << mbi.AllocationBase << endl;
            cout << dec << mbi.RegionSize / pageSize << " pages" << endl;
            static struct
            {
                DWORD dwProtect;
                char const *str;
            } const protectMaps[] =
            {
                { PAGE_EXECUTE, "PAGE_EXECUTE" },
                { PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, "PAGE_EXECUTE_READ" },
                { PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, "PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE" },
                { PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY, "PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY" },
                { PAGE_NOACCESS, "PAGE_NOACCESS" },
                { PAGE_READONLY, "PAGE_READONLY" },
                { PAGE_READWRITE, "PAGE_READWRITE" },
                { PAGE_WRITECOPY, "PAGE_WRITECOPY" }
            };
            for( auto const &pm : protectMaps )
                if( pm.dwProtect == mbi.AllocationProtect )
                {
                    cout << "state: " << pm.str << endl;
                    break;
                }
            if( mbi.Type == MEM_IMAGE )
                cout << "image";
            else if( mbi.Type == MEM_MAPPED )
                cout << "mapped";
            else if( mbi.Type == MEM_PRIVATE )
                cout << "private";
            cout << endl << endl;
        }
    }
    catch( exception const &exc )
    {
        cout << exc.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the program returns mostly null-data except from the number of pages with the first entry, which is the number of *logical* pages of the process minus 32.
What am I doing wrong here ?
The process I tried to query runs under the same token, so there coudln't be any privilege issues.

Comment: It would be far easier to read the code if it wasn't so convoluted. Those immediately evaluated lambda expressions do not serve any particular purpose. There's also lots of opportunity to make this minimal.

Comment: @IInspectable: Functional programming _with_ state simply rocks. Lambdas are a simple but major imrpovement of C++11. I think the other way, i.e when the code would be directly interleaved with the surrounding code without any "encapsulation", is less readable.

Comment: Habit or otherwise, this particular use of immediately evaluated lambdas is just not useful. Things were different if you were binding to `const` variables. But you aren't, making this code *needlessly* hard to read. If you need help, it is in your interest to make the code as easy to follow as possible.

Comment: @IInspectable: It is useful and it gives better readability if you're not fixed to old habits. For you it's just less readable because it's not accustomed to you.

Comment: Invisible code increases the mental burden for readers. That's not just an opinion. You could easily rewrite this as mostly C (and forget for a moment that you're *actually* an absolute Rock Star developer) and increase the reach and value of this question. You can also decide not to.

Comment: @IInspectable is right, this is far from minimal and the chosen style just makes it harder for us to give you help.

Comment: You are asking for help and in my opinion you are making it harder for us to provide that help.

Comment: The usage of VirtualQueryEx() is not correct.  It returns info about a *single* region, and must thus be called repeatedly to traverse the entire address space.  Start at lpAddress = 0, loop with lpAddress += mbi.RegionSize.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If you've got accustomed with functional programming that's not harder to read.

Comment: @BonitaMontero Yes, that's precisely my point

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Functional programming has been in C++ for 11 years.

Comment: That's nice to know

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Hans ! You were right. I thoughth VirtualQueryEx() fills just a number of MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION. If you don't see something obvious you say in Germany that you've got tomatoes on your eyes, and yes, I had tomatoes on my eyes (not because of my style ;-)).

Here's the working code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <charconv>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION>> pageTree( HANDLE hProcess );

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    if( argc < 2 )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    try
    {
        DWORD dwProcessId = [&]() -> DWORD
            {
                DWORD dwRet;
                from_chars_result fcr = from_chars( argv[1], argv[1] + strlen( argv[1] ), dwRet );
                if( fcr.ec != errc() || *fcr.ptr )
                    throw invalid_argument( "process-id unparseable" );
                return dwRet;
            }();
        HANDLE hProcess = [&]() -> HANDLE
            {
                HANDLE hRet = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwProcessId );
                if( !hRet )
                    throw system_error( (int)GetLastError(), system_category(), "can't open process" );
                return hRet;
            }();
        size_t pageSize = []() -> size_t
            {
                SYSTEM_INFO si;
                GetSystemInfo( &si );
                return si.dwPageSize;
            }();
        vector<vector<MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION>> vvmbi = pageTree( hProcess );
        for( vector<MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION> const &vmbi : vvmbi )
        {
            cout << "allocation base: " << hex << vmbi.front().AllocationBase << endl;
            for( MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION const &mbi : vmbi )
            {
                cout << "\tbase address: " << hex << mbi.BaseAddress << endl;
                cout << "\t" << dec << mbi.RegionSize / pageSize << " pages" << endl;
                static struct
                {
                    DWORD dwProtect;
                    char const *str;
                } const protectMaps[] =
                {
                    { PAGE_EXECUTE, "PAGE_EXECUTE" },
                    { PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, "PAGE_EXECUTE_READ" },
                    { PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, "PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE" },
                    { PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY, "PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY" },
                    { PAGE_NOACCESS, "PAGE_NOACCESS" },
                    { PAGE_READONLY, "PAGE_READONLY" },
                    { PAGE_READWRITE, "PAGE_READWRITE" },
                    { PAGE_WRITECOPY, "PAGE_WRITECOPY" }
                };
                for( auto const &pm : protectMaps )
                    if( pm.dwProtect == mbi.AllocationProtect )
                    {
                        cout << "\tstate: " << pm.str << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                if( mbi.Type == MEM_IMAGE )
                    cout << "\timage" << endl;
                else if( mbi.Type == MEM_MAPPED )
                    cout << "\tmapped" << endl;
                else if( mbi.Type == MEM_PRIVATE )
                    cout << "\tprivate" << endl;
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    catch( exception const &exc )
    {
        cout << exc.what() << endl;
    }
}

template<typename Fn>
    requires requires( Fn fn, MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION &mbi ) { { fn( mbi ) } -> std::convertible_to<bool>; }
void enumProcessMemory( HANDLE hProcess, Fn fn );

vector<vector<MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION>> pageTree( HANDLE hProcess )
{
    vector<vector<MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION>> vvmbis;
    enumProcessMemory( hProcess, [&]( MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION &mbi ) -> bool
        {
            
            if( !vvmbis.size() || vvmbis.back().back().BaseAddress != mbi.BaseAddress )
                vvmbis.emplace_back( vector<MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION>() );
            vvmbis.back().emplace_back( mbi );
            return true;
        } );
    return vvmbis;
}

template<typename Fn>
    requires requires( Fn fn, MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION &mbi ) { { fn( mbi ) } -> std::convertible_to<bool>; }
void enumProcessMemory( HANDLE hProcess, Fn fn )
{
        MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
        for( char *last = nullptr; ; last = (char *)mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize )
        {
            size_t nBytes = VirtualQueryEx( hProcess, last, &mbi, sizeof mbi );
            if( nBytes != sizeof mbi )
                if( DWORD dwErr = GetLastError(); dwErr == ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER )
                    break;
                else
                    throw system_error( (int)dwErr, system_category(), "can't query process pages" );
            if( !fn( mbi ) )
                break;
        }
}
```

The code now groups the allocation bases. Its segemented that parts can be extended without changing the framework.